# Linux equivalent of GraphClick?

Tags: data-recovery, image-editor, ocr, graph

Is there a piece of Linux software that does what [GraphClick](http://www.arizona-software.ch/graphclick/) does in Mac OS X?

That is, is there a Linux software that "is a graph digitizer software which allows to automatically retrieve the original (x,y)-data from the image of a scanned graph"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [g3data](http://www.frantz.fi/software/g3data.php) in conjunction with [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).